# Using javascript to get the size of a library on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, filesize

Is it possible to get the size of a javascript library loaded on the site (`<script src='..'></script>`), using JavaScript?

For example, stackoverflow has a file `//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js` , is it possible to select that script tag using jQuery, and then somehow get its file size?

Thanks!

Comment: why would you need to do this on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot access the data of any domain except your domain.

If it is in the same domain you can do something like that:

```
$.ajax({url:'//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js',success:function (a){ alert(a.length) } } )
```

Read more about CORS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

You can serve the file from your server
Then you can do:

```
$.ajax({url:'stub.en.js',success:function (a){ alert(a.length) } } )
```

You just need to develop a small server-side script to load it from the CDN (aka PROXY)